# How do i fix bash error - /dev/tty No such device or address

Tags: linux, bash, curl, google-colaboratory, tty

As the question specifics ,i am getting this error while executing my bash script

In exact terms i get following error

```
bash: line 26: /dev/tty: No such device or address
bash: line 29: /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

Here are the concerned Line 26 and 29 in script respectively which causes the issue

```
read -e -p "Paste the links : " links </dev/tty
read -e -p "Enter your input : " sub </dev/tty
```

If someone wonders, i cannot simply remove writing to </dev/tty from line 26 and 29 , it causes different issues .. So basically i need fix or get alternative for writing to /dev/tty

I am executing my script by running -
`curl raw_link | bash`

Preferably i want a solution which only requires me to my edit my existing script .i don't want to run the script after saving it locally or execute it using any other way apart from `curl raw_link | bash`

ls -l /dev/tty returns the following

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 0 Aug  8 09:28 /dev/tty
```

ls -l </dev/tty returns the following

```
/bin/bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

Also i would like to mention that this issue doesn't seem to be happening on every machine , i intend to use this script on Google Colab where i definitely do get this issue

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your program code in your question.

Comment: I can't reproduce this by copy-pasting that `curl ... | bash` command to my terminal.

Comment: @oguzismail i think it happens on some machines only because one of my friends too didn't got this error on his machine , i intend to run this script in google colab .. there i definitely do get this error

Comment: That sounds right, you should include more details about the *machines* this happens on.

Comment: So is that the output on a machine where this happens? What happens if you put `ls -l /dev/tty` in a gist and execute it in the same fashion with `curl`?

Comment: Your tormented script looks like it pines to be replaced with a simple HTTP API. Can you run a web server on the machine where you run this script?

Comment: This question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: No not `ls -l </dev/tty`; you want it without a redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the bash error, you can try this workaround :

```
tty=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/2)
read ... < $tty
```

$tty contains the actual tty device name.

Comment: Well no, it contains file descriptor 2, which may or may not be your tty.

Comment: @tripleee sorry but due to lack of knowledge on this subject i couldn't understand your advise , currently i am using this solution and its fixes the "/dev/tty no such device or address" issue i mentioned in question . If you are indicating this solution may not work universally everywhere , is there any better approach to it ?

Comment: @Sachin, I should have pointed that the solution I suggested applies to situations where standard error has not been redirected. As long as you do not redirect standard error, it should be okay.

Comment: But that's just a bug unless you commit to never call your script from another script, and a pesky one to fix when you forget that commitment.