# How do i stop the readarray prompt using a specific keyword?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
tty=$(readlink /proc/$$/fd/2)

echo "Paste Content below"
readarray -d '\n' lines < $tty
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" > links.txt
```

So i am using the above script to store a block of text in a variable **lines** and write it to a file **links.txt** .
The thing is when the readarray prompt shows up and i paste my text , i have to stop the read process by doing **ctrl + d** , after that the script proceeds further and writes the stored variable to links.txt

Ideally i want some particular keyword to act as endpoint of my paste where the read prompt ends automatically as soon as that particular word is detected
For example , after i have pasted my content. if i enter `stopread` on a new line it should stop the read process and proceed further with the script
( i have just used the word stopread as an example )

Example - In readarray prompt , if i paste

```
1
2
3
stopread
```

it should store 1 ..3 in variable **lines** and and proceed further in script without the need of doing **ctrl + d** to stop close read prompt

Comment: Are there any other commands after `readarray` that read from the stdin (e.g. prompt the user for input)?

Comment: Well then there is a problem here. You can't discard the lines following `stopread` reliably, the command that *stores single line output* would read the line that immediately follows `stopread`. Try `readarray lines < <(sed '/stopread/q' /dev/tty)` and see how it fails for yourself.

Comment: @oguzismail Yes , there is one more read command below this ( not readarray) , it stores single line output so just pressing enter does the job for read.. also i am writing both the readarray and read to tty , which probably you remember , i didnt added it here as it wasnt the main focus   so i kept code as simple as possible

Comment: You need a loop, not `readarray`/`mapfile`.

Comment: And file descriptor 2 is standard *error*. 0 is *input* and what you should be reading from.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for suggestion , i dont really have much info on file descriptor , i was using it as told by this answer to one of my questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313302/how-do-i-fix-bash-error-dev-tty-no-such-device-or-address

Comment: `readarray -d '\n' lines` reads ```\```-separated strings into lines, not newline-separated. You'd need `readarray -d $'\n' lines` to read 1 line at a time into `lines` but that's not useful for what you're trying to do anyway.

Comment: @Sachin why do you keep trying to use an array to store your input instead of just a scalar variable? There's no indication in your past 2 questions that you need an array and a scalar is much easier to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be doing this with a `while read` loop, since this will allow you to only read the necessary data and no more (due to a buffer size of 1), allowing the rest of the script to consume the rest of the input in a robust way:

```
lines=()
while IFS= read -r line && [[ "$line" != "stopread" ]]
do
  lines+=("$line")
done
```

However, since you ask how to do it `readarray`, you can do:

```
readarray -d '\n' lines < <(sed '/stopread/q')
```

This inherently reads in larger buffer sizes, so it may overconsume input. For example, if the stop word appears half way into a buffer, then the rest of the buffer is necessarily discarded. It's even worse than just being fragile and unpredictable, because you won't be able to spot any problems in casual testing at typical human input speeds, and may therefore more easily be fooled into thinking it's a good solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and recommendation for while loop , i tested both the solutions and while loop solution works perfectly .Personally my purpose is served and i am gonna use the while loop solution , although for viewers of this post , maybe you can debug the readarray solution , currently there are 2 small issues with it   1) it does work if i use tty -  readarray -d '\n' lines < <(sed '/stopread/q') < $tty   2) Without tty ,it works but it even stores the word 'stopread' in the variable along with the lines prior to it

Comment: `readarray -d '\n' lines < <(sed '/stopread/q')` populates `lines[0]` with all of the input lines up to and including `stopread` and the newline after it. ITYM to use `$'\n'` rather than `\n'` as the delimiter but that still includes `stopread` in `lines[]`. I can't imagine why adding `< $tty` would make any difference but none of this is necessary anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63317197/1745001), an array isn't useful for what you're trying to do:

```
$ foo=$(awk '/stopread/{exit} 1' file)
$ echo "$foo"
1
2
3
```

or to read from stdin:

```
$ foo=$(awk '/stopread/{exit} 1')
1
2
3
stopread
$ echo "$foo"
1
2
3
```